keep number-printing and number-storing/calculating distinct
\num command in siunitx package and \fpeval{round()} both can round a value. But I found something different between them. When I use \num command in \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{O{15}m} , $\eval{\?[3]{bb}+22}$ can not work . It seems that \num is unexpandable. Is it possible to use \num instead of \fpeval{round()} ?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{O{15} d() m}
{ #3 =
  \group_begin:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#3}
    \cs_set:Npn \frac ##1##2 {##1/(##2)}
    \cs_set:Npn \times { * }
    \cs_set:Npn \pi { pi }
    \cs_set:Npn \sqrt ##1 { (##1)**.5 }
    \cs_set:Npe \__xcn_tmp:w ##1 { \token_to_str:N ^ (##1) }
    \char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__xcn_tmp:w
    \tl_set_rescan:Nne \l_tmpa_tl { \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^ } } { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \tl_gset:Nn  \l_tmpb_tl  { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } }
    \exp_args:NNNV
  \group_end:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl {\fpeval{round(\l_tmpa_tl,#1) }}
  \IfValueT{#2}{%
    \fp_zero_new:c { l_xcn_var_#2_fp }
    \fp_gset:cn  { l_xcn_var_#2_fp } { \l_tmpb_tl  }
  }
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{O{15}m}
 {%\num[ round-mode=places, round-precision=#1]{\fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#2_fp }}  
   \fpeval{round( \fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#2_fp },#1)}
 }
\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usefpvar}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\eval[4]{\pi/2+\sqrt{5}}$

$\eval[5](aa){\pi/2+\sqrt{5}}$

\?{aa}

$\eval(bb){\pi/2+\sqrt{5}}$

\?{bb}

$\eval{\?[3]{bb}+22}$ % not work when use "\num[ round-mode=places, round-precision=#1]{\fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#2_fp }}" in "\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{O{15}m}" command

\end{document}


\num is a command for typesetting values, and does loads of non-expandable things. However, if you want to use the code-level API, you can work there by expansion.

given that \num is designed for a different purpose, could you explain why you want to substitute \num? then somebody might be able to suggest a way to do that. right now, it's not clear what the motivation for the question is in the first place. you seem to be saying, I'm doing great with this screwdriver - it does just what I want - but I noticed if I try this hammer, the screw doesn't tighten at all. is there any possibility of using this hammer instead? it would make at least some sense if you added that the hammer has a better grip or a longer handle, but you haven't.

Your question seems to be building up on previous, but the query at hand has nothing to do with for example allowing the use of \pi in an expression. You need to tell us why you need to reuse rounded values, why this needs to be expandable, etc.

@JosephWright  I think if I reuse number rounded by \fpeval{} , then the number no longer keep its pricision. So I want to display number rounded with \num in the console document but pass it to \eval without round for calculation.   I feel that it not easy to do this.

but then why is it a problem that \num is not expandable? if you only want to use it for display, that shouldn't be an issue. note that there's no reason you can't do the same without num, though. but I would use an fp variable to store an fp. do you mean the console or the document or both?

@cfr there is no problem using an fp variable to store an fp. The problem is to use value rounded by \fpeval .  I doubt \fpeval{(round)} no longer keep a number precision compared with \num since \num don't change a value original precision. But \num can't be recognized by \eval command. I doubt this may be the reson  why numerica package write a value to a file for reuse .  Of course, there is no problem about \eval if I accept precision lose cuased by \fpeval{(round)} .

sorry. I'm lost. \num just prints a number in a certain format. the stored number is used, but it isn't altered. you could alternatively print a number in a certain format using the number stored in an fp variable without altering the number stored in that variable. the only difference I can see is that if you round with fp, you could use the rounded result for further calculations. but you certainly don't have to. you can keep number-printing and number-storing/calculating distinct.

@cfr if I seperate  number-printing and  number-evaluation , then I "can keep number-printing and number-storing/calculating distinct" . While in above code, \eval make it impossible since it reads a variable directly from mandatory argument (or number-printing) .

is it that you want e.g. the aa variable to produce the rounded version when printed but the non-rounded version when evaluated? because the stored value right now doesn't lose precision i.e. it is not rounded. the printed version is rounded, but not stored.

yes . that‘s the problem I try to solve. So I wonder if \num can be expandable and "produce the rounded version when printed but the non-rounded version when evaluated" .

Clearly, if you want to store both the non-rounded value and the ability to reproduce the rounded one, you need to store 2 pieces of information rather than only 1.
So perhaps something like this?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{om}
{%\num[ round-mode=places, round-precision=#1]{\fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#2_fp }}
  \IfValueTF { #1 }
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { #1 }
  }{
    \int_if_exist:cTF { g_xcn_var_#2_int }
    {
      \int_set_eq:Nc \l_tmpa_int  { g_xcn_var_#2_int }
    }{
      \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 15 }
    }
  }
  \fpeval{round( \fp_use:c { g_xcn_var_#2_fp },\l_tmpa_int)}
}
\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usefpvar}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvarnude}{om}
{
  \fp_to_decimal:c { g_xcn_var_#2_fp }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{O{15} d() m}
{ #3 =
  \group_begin:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \? \usefpvarnude
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#3}
    \cs_set:Npn \frac ##1##2 {##1/(##2)}
    \cs_set:Npn \times { * }
    \cs_set:Npn \pi { pi }
    \cs_set:Npn \sqrt ##1 { (##1)**.5 }
    \cs_set:Npe \__xcn_tmp:w ##1 { \token_to_str:N ^ (##1) }
    \char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__xcn_tmp:w
    \tl_set_rescan:Nne \l_tmpa_tl { \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^ } } { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \tl_gset:Nn  \l_tmpb_tl  { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } }
    \exp_args:NNNV
  \group_end:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl {\fpeval{round(\l_tmpa_tl,#1) }}
  \IfValueT{#2}{%
    \fp_zero_new:c { g_xcn_var_#2_fp }
    \fp_gset:cn  { g_xcn_var_#2_fp } { \l_tmpb_tl  }
    \int_new:c { g_xcn_var_#2_int }
    \int_gset:cn { g_xcn_var_#2_int } { #1 }
  }
  \cs_set_eq:NN \? \usefpvar
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\eval[4]{\pi/2+\sqrt{5}}$

$\eval[5](aa){\pi/2+\sqrt{5}}$

\?{aa}

$\eval(bb){\pi/2+\sqrt{5}}$

\?{bb}

$\eval{\?[3]{bb}+22}$

\end{document}

This substitutes a different command for \?, \usefpvarnude inside an \eval{} statement, so that the unrounded value is used for further calculations. It also stores the rounding request, if specified, and \usefpvar is modified to reuse that value if the optional argument is unspecified when printing the variable.
Note that you should never write something like \fp_gset:Nc { l_xcn_var_#2_fp } because ldenotes a *local* variable, whereasgsetsets a *global* one. For this reason, I changed yourls to g`s.
There are certainly better approaches, but they would involve altering your code in ways you probably don't want, so I made minimal changes to the extant framework.

thanks a lot @cfr for making the macro perfect.

Comparing $\eval[5](aa){\pi/2+\sqrt{5}}$  and variable \?{aa}  with $\eval(aa){\pi/2+\sqrt{5}}$  and variable \?{aa} ,  I found \?{aa} real value is rounded by [5] . So how to make aa be unrounded too ?

@xcn what do you mean by 'real value'? your original code printed \?{aa} unrounded. my answer prints \?{aa} rounded. the stored value is not rounded, so if you use \?{aa} inside \eval{}, it uses the unrounded value. if you use it outside, it uses the rounded value. I'm not sure what you're comparing.

real value mean unrounded value. Is it possible to keep \?{aa} unrounded no matter it is inside or before \eval braces ? and optional argument just change its output format.

@xcn \?{aa} isn't a number, so it can't be rounded or unrounded. \? is a macro which absorbs arguments. your original code - i.e. not my answer - already did what you are now asking i.e. you could use the optional argument to round it; o/w \?{aa} returned the unrounded value. at least, it rounded to 15 places. but if you just changed O{15} to o, you would have unrounded if you didn't specify the optional argument. but I am not really clear what you're asking.

I'm asking leave all value unrounded when storing/calculating and rounded when printing if optional argument  is used.  Instead if  changing O{15} to o ,  I found it useful if I change om in \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{om} to O{15}m in your example.
